# Iron Man villain - a being made of "living gold"

Tags: marvel, comics, character-identification, iron-man

In this story, smugglers are stealing gold needed for circuitry made by Stark's company and as Iron Man, Stark sets out to track them down.

It turns out the smugglers aren't stealing the gold for conventional criminals, but a giant whose body is composed of living gold, who "feeds" on the metal by absorbing it somehow.

He (the giant) says he would be unable to move except for a "spark" (or something to that affect) that keeps his body somewhat unstable - at the end of the comic the "spark" dies out, implying that this kills the villain.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midas_(comics)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The villain you're referring to is [Mordecai Midas](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mordecai_Midas_(Earth-616)), and I believe the specific issue you described is *[Marvel Super-Heroes Vol 2 #13](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Super-Heroes_Vol_2_13)*. The plot involves Iron Man tracking down stolen shipments of gold bars, which it turns out are being absorbed by Midas. Midas also mentions an electrode which keeps his metallic structure unstable, thus preventing him from becoming a living statue. The electrode shorts out at the end of the story, and Midas sinks helplessly into the seabed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice find! Out of interest who's the character in the last few panes? That's not pepper is it?

Comment: @Liath - It's not Pepper. It was a random woman Stark met in that issue, named Darby. Her last name was never revealed, and as far as I know, this story was her only appearance.